# Login validation using JSTL (JSP) but stuck with error : "Unterminated &lt;sql:setDataSource tag"

Tags: mysql, jsp, tomcat, jstl

I am getting following error when I try to perform login validation using JSTL Custom Tags
**org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /checlLogin.jsp(12,38) Unterminated <sql:setDataSource tag**

Please find below software specifications I have
-        I have placed JSTL.jar and Standard.jar at CATALINE_HOME...\WEB-INF\lib
-   Working with server: **Apache Tomcat/6.0.29**
-   Servlet Specification: **2.5** 
-   JSP version: **2.1**
-   MySQL Sever: **5.1.47**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%> 
<%@ taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>  


<c:set var='uName' value='${param.username}'/>  
<c:set var='uPassword' value='${param.password}'/>  
<sql:setDataSource var="db" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "sohail"/> 
<sql:query var="query1"  dataSource="${db}"
sql="select * from login where loginID == '${uName}'">
</sql:query>  
<c:forEach   var="row" tems="${sqlQuery.rows}">
<c:set var='dbUserName' value='${row.username}'/>  
<c:set var='dbUserPassword' value='${row.password}'/>  
</c:forEach>
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${dbUserName eq uName}">
    <c:redirect url="http://stackoverflow.com/"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
    <c:redirect url="http://stackoverflow.com/"/>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Kindly suggest where I am wrong?

I was learning JSP using JAVA Code but then I came to know that JAVA Code is not recommended in JAVA. So eventually I have to work in JSTL.

Answer (score 2):

The tag syntax is invalid. Those commas doesn't belong there. You need to set the username and password each as an attribute as per the [`sql:setDataSource` tag documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/sql/setDataSource.html).

```
<sql:setDataSource var="db" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" user="root" password="sohail" />
```

That said, I don't want to disappoint you, but it is **also not** recommended to use JSTL SQL taglibs. It should only be used for quick prototyping / demo. But in real practice you should be doing all this DB interaction jobs in standalone Java classes which you can then import in your servlet and access/display in your JSP. Also all business/domain jobs should be (indirectly) done by a servlet. This gives you the benefits of much better reusability, maintainability and testability.

To be clear: using [JSTL](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) instead of scriptlets is perfectly fine, you should only avoid the [`sql`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/sql/tld-summary.html) and [`xml`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/x/tld-summary.html) taglibs as they are intented for quick prototyping only. The [`core`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html), [`fn`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html) and [`fmt`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/tld-summary.html) taglibs are fine.

#### See also:

- [How to avoid Java code in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)
- [DAO tutorial - Second part contains JSP/Servlet integration example](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html)

Answer (score 0):

and also

```
<sql:query var="query1"  dataSource="${db}"
```

sql="select * from login where loginID == '${uName}'">

not like this
`<sql:query var="query1"  dataSource="${db}"
select * from login where loginID == '${uName}'
</sql:query>`

just like that

Answer (score 0):

above is mistake that

```
<sql:query var="query1" dataSource="${db}" select * from login where loginID == '${uName}' </sql:query>
```

but right one is

```
<sql:query var="query1" dataSource="${db}">
select * from login where loginID == '${uName}'
</sql:query>
```

this mistake i show that's why i told you because i am also beginner to JSTL